# Convert a list of nested items to a Dataframe in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to extract data from a nested JSON file and I was able to explode out the data I need to a list. Sample list below:

```
[Row(['rrrr644', '0838-60C', '0', None, '2556', None, '{ }', '2875']), 
Row(['werw522', 'C8FC-DDD', '0', '3762', None,  '{ }', '1145']),
 etc]
```

I am having trouble pulling the data from the 'Rows' into a dataframe.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Which error do you get?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - I created a schema and attempted to use:

df = spark.createDataFrame(DF,schema)

But I get an error:
ValueError: Length of object (1) does not match with length of fields (8)

As the fields are within the Row( )  - I do not know how to pull them out to get them into a DataFrame.